# Tags for musical works (pieces of music, albums, …)?

Tags: discussion, tags

Do we want to use tags for specific musical works (pieces of music, albums etc.), or are tags for the musicians sufficient?

**Example:** Currently we have three questions ([q1](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/191/the-right-here-right-now-sample-in-right-here-right-now), [q2](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/260/waking-up-to-find-your-loves-not-real-in-right-here-right-now), [q3](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/308/the-radio-talk-in-right-here-right-now-about-the-rockafeller-skank)) about the song *Right Here, Right Now*. Should we tag these questions with a tag about the song?

Things to keep in mind:

- Many titles are not unique - we’d need to add *something* as disambiguation in such cases.
- Covers, remixes etc. - they could (or could not) use the "original" work’s tag.
- Threshold - tags could be created as soon as there is one question about a work, or only after some threshold (e.g., 2+ questions).

Answer (score 11):

I believe song-specific tags would simply be *too* granular. Tags are designed to help categorize content into broader swaths, and I cannot imagine a site about music appreciation needing a *Stairway to Heaven* "department" to help categorize that content. Tags categories are generally broader than that.

Comment: What would you suggest for questions about albums that don’t have a single artist/band? For example, compilations, chart albums etc., or soundtracks with different composers? [For example](http://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/388/47), the Shenmue OST does not have a single responsible artist. In this case, it has at least one tag ([tag:unknown-composer], which I just created), but what if I’d have a different question about this particular soundtrack album?

Comment: @unor, maybe the [soundtrack] tag is enough?